# Creaking From Bottom Bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket, pedals

I'm not too familiar with the correct terminology for bike parts so please bear with me.

I recently bought a mountain bike and have started to notice a loud creaking sound coming from the pedal/bracket area.  I have noticed that it makes noise when I put more pressure on the pedals from accelerating from a standstill.  I also hear the noise when I am riding while standing up.

Any tips, suggestions, or knowledge on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the frame made of? Have you checked that the cranks are on nice and tight? Did you buy the bike new, or could it be a case of worn parts?

Comment: it appears to be a steel frame.  i'm not too sure.  i honestly don't know much about it.  the cranks appear to be on tight.

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://sheldonbrown.com/creaks.html - since bicycles are made of hollow tubing, its hard to track where sounds are actually coming from since the tubing can transmit sound.

Comment: Definitely check out Sheldon's page mentioned by @Batman. Also, check the "Related" question to the right. There are already a number of questions about creaking bottom brackets on the site. If you feel that none of these addresses your issue, vote to reopen your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nothing is wrong with your frame, your bottom bracket probably needs to be properly greased up and re-tightened to the right torque specification.

Frankly, unless you're interested in rolling up your sleeves, buckling down and [familiarizing](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/torque-specifications-and-concepts) yourself with bicycle mechanics and purchasing all the necessary tools, just take it to your local bicycle shop and have them tighten things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do:! Take your pedals off and put a new pair on. Make sure it's still creaking. I've been sure multiple times that something was wrong with my BB, switched the pedals, and the noise stopped.

If you do this and still get the noise, take apart the BB and re-grease. If it's loose bearing, inspect the races, clean, and regrease. If it's a sealed bearing BB, grease the non-drive-side cup outside and in. Make sure that the drive-side cup is flush with the frame.

Comment: Sounds like an expensive experiment.